# React-Native Redux and SQL Database

Tags: react-native, rest, express, redux, mariadb

I'm trying to implement a simple app displaying data fetched via an API. I'm exposing my own API with an express server. With the API I can basically interact with my SQL database.

For the front-end and especially state management I wanted to use Redux, but I'm not sure how Redux can be used to manage state while simultaneously fetching data from a database / updating the database via the API.

Does Redux hold the same information as the database? How would one implement a combination of Redux and a database?

Answer (score 0):

Redux is for state management. That means it basically has the same functionality as the react native state, that means they are going to get resetted when you restart your app.

A database on the other hand is used to store data also when you restart the App.

So, yes, it's definitly useful to implement both. Information which is going to be saved until it gets deleted should be saved in the database and information that triggers a re-render or basic information like if a checkbox is checken should be save in the state or Redux.